# javascript file's order is not correct in drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, printing

Javascript file's order is not correct in Drupal. On other pages other than print page the order of script files are correct. The files are `drupal.js` and `google_analytics_reports.js`

Since the order is not correct it is causing error

```
"ReferenceError: Drupal is not defined"
```

Please help me to `change the order of the files in Print pages`(When we try to take a print out of the page, we will get this print page).

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure that this is a problem of the js files order and not
   something else?
2. Are the same js files loaded on print and normal pages?
3. What files are inside the /templates folder of your theme (or
   generally files with tpl.php extension under your theme folder)?

If you just need a **template for the printing mode** install the [print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module and copy the print.tpl.php file into your theme templates folder. Then edit it as you prefer.